# iron-router waitOn Meteor.user()

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I would use Meteor.user() in *data* iron-router, but this is undefined at start...

I'm trying with:

```
waitOn: function() {
   return curretUserHandle;
},
data: function() {
   // access to Meteor.user().username, give me undefined

[...]

var curretUserHandle = {
    ready: function () {
        return 'undefined' !== typeof Meteor.user();
    }
};
```

but *data* function of route is always call before curretUserHandle.ready() return true

I know that i can add *if(Meteor.user())* in *data*, but this option don't like.

Why *data* don't wait that *Meteor.user()* is ready?

Comment: Do you have `Router.onBeforeAction('loading')` anywhere? Without it, `waitOn` wont wait.

Comment: Yes @PeppeL-G, I have: `loadingTemplate: 'Loading'` and `Router.onBeforeAction('loading');`... The problem occur only when user go directly to the route or refresh page (F5)

Comment: I am curious why you're complicating the hadle so much. I am pretty much sure that all you need is just `return !!Meteor.user()`.

Comment: ehehe... you have right @apendua. I have done a copy&paste from another place and I don't taken care to the code...but the problem remain :(

Comment: @elbowz Hmm that's mysterious.

Comment: thanks anyway @apendua! ..btw, I think the correct handle should be `'undefined' !== typeof Meteor.user()`. return `true` also if no user is logged...but the problem is that `data` don't want wait!! :(

Answer (score 1):

Adding https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/fast-render 'magically' solves this.

However, please read the note on necessary security measures:
https://meteorhacks.com/fast-render/security-measures/

Comment: I believe it only solves the race condition between the iron-router initialization code running on first page refresh and the check for user login data.
Other reactive variables worked fine for me with waitOn.

Answer (score 0):

Only as workaround can be used:

`if(this.ready())`

in `data` function

Comment: I've a situation where this.ready() returns true without the data being subscribed. After checking the in console, the data is nowhere. iron:router has too many magical problems.